# Shopware6 multishops like in Shopware5

Tags: shopware

I find the Option of Salechannels in Shopware 6, but does it work like MultiShop system in Shopware 5?

Is it possible to have 2+ Shopware6 front-end shops with 1 Shopware6 backend? If so, how?

I've looked in the Docs, but I think I miss it somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new storefront salesChannel as described here https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/saleschannel?category=shopware-6-en/swsaleschannel
Assign it to the domain you want and a root category used for navigation.

After that you can define the visibility of products for each salesChannel in the product detail pages.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer, youre right. I have another question, would it work on a Subdomain, just to see if it works? Or is it only domain specific?

Comment: subdomain should be fine